# how to open shared preferences data in android XML

Tags: java, android, xml, sharedpreferences

I want to make a game level logic. The game itself similar with logo quiz game. It has locked and unlocked level. I need to display the locked and unlocked level based on the score which saved in shared preferences. so, how can I access the score variable in XML file?

Answer (score 0):

declare these two variable in your activity

```
android.content.SharedPreferences someData;
public static String filename = "mySharedString";
```

initialize the `Shared Preferences` like this:

```
someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
```

you can add elements to the `Shared Preferences` like this:

```
android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor editor = someData.edit();
            editor.putString("sharedString", stringData);
            editor.commit();
```

you can retrieve data like this:

```
String dataReturned = someData.getString("sharedString","Couldn't load data");
```

The `Couldn't load data` will be set to the `dataReturned` variable if the `sharedString` is not existed in the Shared Preferences

also check this question [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)